# Replacing strings with numbers in Python for Data Analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, data-analysis

How to assign dynamiclly numbers to each unique value? I've searched but I can only see 1 answer:

```
# creating a dict file 
gender = {'male': 1,'female': 2}
  
# traversing through dataframe
# Gender column and writing
# values where key matches
data.Gender = [gender[item] for item in data.Gender]
print(data)
```

But these answer uses fixed numbers. What if I can't assign manually every value in `gender`? How could I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just answer myself!

```
dictChangeValues = {}

for d in data.columns:
    i = 0
    aux = data[d].unique()
    dictChangeValues[d] = {}
    for n in aux:
        dictChangeValues[d][n] = i
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing data analysis, then I suppose using `scikit-learn` is not an overhead for you.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

>>> LabelEncoder().fit_transform(["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"])
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1])
```